# Understanding a ZVS Oscillator in-depth

Tags: voltage, power, current, oscillator, stability

For a project I've been building, I've been using the (overused) ZVS oscillator that can be found online. So far it's been working great transferring power wirelessly, but I'm interested in understanding the schematic.[[image: [1]]

I understand that the frequency of the oscillating wave in the lc tank is given by f=1/(2pi*sqrt(LC)).

I also understand that in the ZVS configuration, mosfets only switch between on and off right when their gate voltage is 0.

What I'm having troubles understanding:

1.) What exactly are the paths of the currents? I think one path is from L1 to the LC tank, and out to the drain of M1, but since now the current is in the opposite direction, what exactly is the other path?

2.) Why does the switching effect occur? Is there current on the gates of the mosfets?

3.) Are the chokes used to suppress any AC from coming back to the bench supply?

I've looked online and while I've run a spice simulation, I'm still having difficulties understanding it. Thank you in advance!

What I think happens (and I'd appreciate corrections):

Let's focus on gate of transistor M1. Current follows from the top resistor, and most of the current will flow towards D2 since the resistance at R3 is very high. Since the Vgs on the mosfet is the voltage on R3, and most of the current is flowing through D2, then M1 will shutoff.

If I remove M1 from the picture, the only path remaining is from L2 to the top of the LC tank, and that current meets the current from the diode and goes down the drain of M2.

Now that M1 is off, and it's ZVS, it will slowly switch to being on, and slowly the current from gate of M2 will go to the drain of M1, and the new path, if we take M2 to be off, is from L1, through the bottom of the LC tank, and through the drain of M1. The current thhrough D1, from gate of M2 to drain M1 also goes through the diode to the drain.

Does this seem correct? I'm still not sure as to what the RF chokes are for (L1,L2)

Comment: You have what looks like a schematic in LTSpice. Why don't you run a simulation and study what directions the current flows?

Comment: @MichaelKaras I've gotten the circuit to oscillate using different valued components, and I've tried sitting on it for the past two weeks. Ill try to post what I think happens and hopefully I can get some corrections

Comment: @MichaelKaras Edited it, hopefully someone can chime in!

Comment: These RF chokes are here to separate the LC tank circuit (L3 C1)  from the Vsupply because the amplitude of the LC tank oscillation will be larger than Vsupply. Do you know how an LC tank circuit work?  The resistors bias both MOSFETs in the ON state but the diodes allow to pull the opposing MOSFET's gate voltage down to shut it off in the rhythm of an L3 C1 tank circuit.

Comment: Thank you - So are the current paths correct in my original post? @G36

Comment: Play with this http://tinyurl.com/y29uuaea And what you must remember is that when you take a changed capacitor and connected this capacitor across the inductor, the LC tank circuit will start to oscillations by itself.